# hide apps programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, springboard

I need to hide my app programmatically from the springboard as the "Nike+ iPod" app does. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

PS: It's an in-house app and I'm not planning to submit to the app store.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I achieved it,
In the Info.plist add following lines,

```
<key>SBAppTags</key>
<array>
<string>hidden</string>
</array>
```

I tried with JB Device

Comment: This works with non-jailbroken devices, too. It's just that Apple won't approve such an app in their App Store.

Comment: Did you find out how to show/hide app programmatically for non-jailbroken device?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have tried this before but I was not able to get it to work.

Comment: you will have to fire uicache command from mobile user (`su mobile -c uicache`) to update the springboard/backboard